# Docker - set DNS from inside container - for VPN?

Tags: docker, dns, vpn

I'm trying to set up a docker container to access my VPN (IVPN).  I want to use the DNS of the VPN, **but** the DNS is selected based on the IP address I'm assigned - which occurs within the container...

https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/163/What-is-the-IP-address-of-your-DNS-servers.html

```
To work out the address of the closest DNS server simply look at
the IP assigned to you when you connect. The DNS servers are in
the format 10.x.x.1. For example, if you receive the address
10.16.4.66 then the DNS is on 10.16.4.1.
```

1. Is there some way of updating the DNS from within the container?
2. Or can I (massively over-engineer a solution by...) start the container, get the IP address assigned by the VPN, then (somehow) do a DNS update from the host?
3. Do I just give up and hard code some DNS servers that aren't "closest"

[Edit thanks to @MrE] I want to run openvpn IN the container (so I'll use someone else's image) - and have other containers use this one as their only connection to the 'net.  Basically, I'm trying to build fully isolated containers and then have their connections configurable via either our corporate (or other commercial) VPN.

Comment: are you setting up a VPN with docker or trying to reach a VPN with a docker container? You seem to indicate you are trying to setup a VPN server container. I would suggest not to reinvent the wheel:  https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn

Comment: f al you need is a DNS to the outside world, easiest is to use Google: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, if you're connected to the outside, you will find it over the network.

Comment: @MrE - Using the Google DNS will still work if my VPN connection goes down, so there is possible information leakage.  Using the VPN for everything means that if the connection drops then nothing escapes (or at least that is the intention!)

Comment: if the VPN drops, your traffic will go whichever way it would without the VPN. Your VPN can set the client routes to force all traffic through it, but if the connection drops the routes will be removed and back to no VPN state. So unless you block everything but the VPN on the client, i don't see how you can avoid leakage.

Comment: Spot on.  In my VM implementation I'm using http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=108381#p517286 to block everything else -  but without either physically setting the DNS, or using `update-resolv-conf` I'm still using the DNS...  :-(